# How to pass a C++ object variable to Lua script, in order to animate a sprite

Tags: c++, animation, lua, sprite

I have a Win32 app that creates a window, starts up DirectX, and creates a sprite, all in C++. My sprite currently animates with the following code at the end of the `Sprite::Update()` function:

```
curFrame++;
if (curFrame >= numFrames)
    curFrame = 0;
```

Now, that little bit of code needs to be ran with a Lua script. How do I go about replacing this C++ code to access a Lua script that has almost the same lines of code. I thought about passing the C++ Sprite class's `curFrame` and `numFrames` variables to the Lua script, but I don't know how.

Any assistance is much appreciated. This can not be done with another library or someone else's code. I just need a push in the right direction.

Comment: Are you asking about how to call the above C++ code snippet from Lua or do you want to port the above C++ code snippet over to Lua? Your question isn't really clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of good tutorials about how to push params to the Lua functions and how to integrate Lua to C++ in general:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11508/Integrating-Lua-into-C
- http://csl.sublevel3.org/lua/